My ETH is stuck... I have 6 transactions that are stuck now. Please help
I've tried to cancel all of them, and/or re-submit the ones I can with higher fees. Nothing seems to work, they all say that there's an older transaction that is stuck, but there isn't any older transaction. (Only the 6 now)

Maybe try with some other wallet? Would be also helpful to somehow see which transactions are waiting in the mempool for your address, but unsure if such tools exist

0x7cf9ebc5a424cbdcd409a489559433b9e900f3ead355a9d18aef8d26fba74bd8

Sorry, no idea what that hash is. Nothing in eth mainnet at least.

You can do the following things . Try to change the rpc in the metamask . This has fixed my pending transaction on testnet might work on mainnet . Also you are on ETH mainnet right ?
